# IE8 issue with Bootstrap 3 and testing in IE emulation modes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-8, warnings, ie8-compatibility-mode

I'm creating a website with Bootstrap 3.3.2 and on IE8 I have this alert displaying every time I refresh or change page :

```
WARNING: You appear to be using IE8 in IE7 emulation mode.
IE emulation modes can behave significantly differently from ACTUAL older version of IE.
PLEASE DON'T FILE BOOTSTRAP BUGS based on testing in IE emulation modes !
```

However I use a standard IE8 (Version : 8.0.6001.18702CO).

Any idea for resolve this problem and delete this warning alert ?

Comment: Did you check http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete this file : `bootstrap/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js`

Or just remove this line in your HTML template :

```
<script src="bootstrap/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
```